# how to check if the document updated was really modified?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an "items" collection and this is an example document in the collection:

```js
{ "id": 0, "price": 23.55 }
```

I'm updating writing a query that updates an item's price,
but want to check if the price field has really modified.

For example, following query is legal but
does not actually modify the document.

```js
db.collection('items').updateOne(
  { id: 0 },
  { $set: { price: 23.55 } }
);
```

Is there any methods I can achieve this?

Comment: Which driver are you using? nodejs, mongoose etc?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar It's nodejs driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`updateOne` will return `nModified` you can get to know whether the document was modified or not.

```
{  "n": 1,  "nModified": 1 }
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#updateOne

[https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpCallback](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#%7EupdateWriteOpCallback)

---

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate

Use `findOneAndUpdate` with `returnOriginal` set to false, you'll get the updated document in the callback.

```
const options = { returnOriginal: false; } // to return the updated document
findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback)
```

[https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~findAndModifyCallback](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#%7EfindAndModifyCallback)

> Document returned from the findAndModify command. If no documents were found, value will be null by default (returnOriginal: true), even if a document was upserted; if returnOriginal was false, the upserted document will be returned in that case.